# Generar cadenas de caracteres aleatorios en C

Tags: c, string, random, caracteres

estaba creando un programa para generar cadenas de caracteres aleatorios en C y encontré el siguiente código en internet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

// maximo y minimo son inclusivos
int aleatorio_en_rango(int minimo, int maximo) {
    return minimo + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (maximo - minimo + 1) + 1);
}

void cadena_aleatoria(int longitud, char *destino) {
    char muestra[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
    for (int x = 0; x < longitud; x++) {
        int indiceAleatorio = aleatorio_en_rango(0, (int) strlen(muestra) - 1);
        destino[x] = muestra[indiceAleatorio];
    }
}

int main(void) {
#define LONGITUD_DESEADA 50
    srand(getpid());
    char destino[LONGITUD_DESEADA + 1] = "";// El +1 es por el carácter nulo que marca el fin de la cadena
    cadena_aleatoria(LONGITUD_DESEADA, destino);
    printf("%s", destino);
}
```

El programa funciona, pero no entiendo muy bien como utiliza la función rand() en la linea `return minimo + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (maximo - minimo + 1) + 1);`.
¿Alguien me podría explicar lo qué hace? Llevo poco programando y esta función no la he utilizado mucho. Gracias.

Comment: No estoy seguro de que es lo que estás preguntando ... lo que hace esa función lo puedes consultar en [su documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand)

Comment: No es lo que hace la función en si, sino como la está utilizando. He visto otros ejemplos que definían limites superiores e inferiores del estilo "valor = 10 + rand() % (26-10)", pero en este caso la estructura es algo distinta y no acabo de ver muy bien como funciona.

Comment: Es una operación matemática. El problema que planteas no tiene nada que ver con `rand()`. Esa función te devuelve un número pseudoaleatorio ... y ya. Para entender esa línea que comentas coge papel y lápiz y analízala. Reemplaza `rand()` por `X` si crees que así te va a resultar más sencillo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para generar cadenas de manera aleatorio, debes que crear tu diccionario de caracteres el cual se servirá para poder editar la posición.

Ya con eso puedes crear caracteres con la longitud que tu desees.

```
char *generate_key(int max){
    // diccionario de caracteres
    char diccionario[] = {
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
        'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
        'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K',
        'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V',
        'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
        '!', '#', '@', '%', '&', '*', '-', '{', '}', '[', ']',
        '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
    };

    srand(getpid()); // genero una semilla para poder tener un numero random
    char *key = malloc(sizeof(char)+max); // le doy la cantidad de memoria a la variable que guardara la clave
    int len = (int)strlen(diccionario); // obtengo la longitud de caracteres del diccionario

    for(int i = max; i >= 0; i--){
        key[i] += diccionario[rand() % len]; // se genera la clave aleatoria
    }
    
    return key; // retorno la clave
}
```

Nótese que uso la función `srand()`, esto permite crear una semilla para la generación de números random, ya que el problema que tuve es que siempre me generaba la misma cadena hasta un determinado tiempo, con esto se generaría una nueva semilla para poder crear números verdaderamente aleatorios.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hace la función aleatorio_en_rango es devolver un numero aleatorio entre los 2 parámetros que se le entregan. por ejemplo puede retornar 6 si es entre 0 y 10.

Ocupa este numero aleatorio para tomar un caracter de la cadena muestra[], siguiendo el ejemplo si al numero aleatorio es 6 tomara el caracter 'g' , es por ello que aleatorio funciona entre 0 y el largo de muestra, para que siempre tome un caracter de la cadena, (si en un futuro quisieses agregar o eliminar caracteres solo debes modificar la cadena y no el método en cuestión).

finalmente repite el proceso varias veces para formar la cadena aleatoria.